# How to set remoteId and server certificate check Strongswan IKEv2 ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, strongswan, ikev2

I am a new member in IKEv2, and I want to install an IKEv2 vpn on an ubuntu 18.04 server,  I did it through [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ikev2-vpn-server-with-strongswan-on-ubuntu-18-04-2) , but I have a couple of questions.

First how can I configure its remote id, because I use a url for that in my ios app.

The second is how can I omit using cert file in client, I mean I want to login it with just username and password and I don’t want to trust the cert in client devices, because I use it in an app.

Comment: What remote ID exactly? What do you mean with "use a url for that"? The tutorial you referenced doesn't use client certificates, so not sure if your second question aims at the self-signed server certificate. Just create your server certificate via Let's Encrypt if you want to avoid installing your CA on the clients.

Comment: @ecdsa thanks for comment, I installed it on an ubuntu server and I use Ip for vpn server address, but I want to use a url ( ex: sec.mydomain.com) for all my servers remote id. And the next I don’t want to install the cert in clients, because I must use it on an ios app

Comment: Just configure that domain name as identity in _leftid_ then (must match a subjectAltName extension in the certificate). And as I said, get your certificate for your server from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) (or a commercial CA) so you don't have to install anything on the client.

Comment: @ecdsa thank you so so much, if you can put it on the answer for allowing me to accept as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a domain name instead of an IP address as identity of the server, just configure it as local identity there (e.g. in *leftid* in ipsec.conf). The configured identity has to be contained in a *subjectAlternativeName* extension in the server certificate.

To avoid having to install any certificates on the clients, use a server certificate issued by an already trusted Certificate Authority (CA). You can do so for free via [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), or alternatively buy a certificate from a commercial CA.